# returning multiple values from multiple functions?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, multiple-value

Often, I have `main` functions that run multiple functions in my common lisp apps.

```lisp
(main 
  (run-function-1...)
  (run-function-2...)
  (run-function-3...)
  (run-function-4...)
  (run-function-5...))
```

At the moment, I have this situation where each function in `main` returns a varying number of values. However, the number of return values are also fixed.

I want `main` to return all values from all function.

```lisp
(main 
  (run-function-1...) ;<--- returns 2 values
  (run-function-2...) ;<--- returns 2 values
  (run-function-3...) ;<--- returns 1 values
  (run-function-4...) ;<--- returns 3 values
  (run-function-5...)) ;<--- returns 2 values

;; main should return 10 values
```

When I do `multiple-value-bind` inside of main it doesnt capture all function returns. Because it only accepts one value-form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`multiple-value-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_mult_1.htm) + [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) + [`values-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_vals_l.htm#values-list), but I think the most straightforward is [`multiple-value-call`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_multip.htm#multiple-value-call):

```
(multiple-value-call #'values
  (run-function-1 ...) 
  (run-function-2 ...)
  (run-function-3 ...) 
  (run-function-4 ...)
  (run-function-5 ...))
```

If you want to return a list, replace `#'values` with `#'list`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to repack the returned values into a new values call:

```
(defun run-function-1 ()
  (values 1 2))
(defun run-function-2 ()
  (values 3 4 5))
(defun main () 
  (multiple-value-bind (a b) (run-function-1) 
    (multiple-value-bind (c d e) (run-function-2)
    (values a b c d e))))
(main)
1 ;
2 ;
3 ;
4 ;
5
```